# -[PUPhotosGridViewController assetAtIndexPath:] NSRangeException

Tags: ios, exception, ios7

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x2ff42f03 __exceptionPreprocess + 130
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3a6d7ce7 objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2fed6eff -[__NSOrderedSetM objectAtIndex:] + 202
3  PhotosUI                       0x369ab149 -[PUPhotosGridViewController assetAtIndexPath:]
4  PhotosUI                       0x369b55b7 -[PUPhotosGridViewController collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:]
5  UIKit                          0x3298e42b -[UICollectionView _selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 174
6  UIKit                          0x3298e36f -[UICollectionView _userSelectItemAtIndexPath:] + 154
7  UIKit                          0x3298e055 -[UICollectionView touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 380
8  UIKit                          0x328f8f97 forwardTouchMethod + 234
9  UIKit                          0x3276a541 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 5528
10 UIKit                          0x327a2325 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 772
11 UIKit                          0x327a1c4b -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 666
12 UIKit                          0x32776e75 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
13 UIKit                          0x32775541 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7120
14 CoreFoundation                 0x2ff0dfe7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
15 CoreFoundation                 0x2ff0d4af __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 206
16 CoreFoundation                 0x2ff0bc9f __CFRunLoopRun + 630
17 CoreFoundation                 0x2fe767a9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
18 CoreFoundation                 0x2fe7658b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
19 GraphicsServices               0x34de36d3 GSEventRunModal + 138
20 UIKit                          0x327d5891 UIApplicationMain + 1136
```

Does somebody knows this error? I only know what happens when you select a photo from Camera Roll in UIImagePickerController.

**Update**
Code:

```
- (void)addPhotoFromSource:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)source {
if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:source])
return;
NSString* imageType = (__bridge NSString*)kUTTypeImage;
if (![[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:source] containsObject:imageType])
return;
self.pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.pickerController.sourceType = source;
self.pickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:imageType];
self.pickerController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:self.pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Update**
My didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info {
UIImage *imageOriginal = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
UIViewController* vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Crop"];
vc.image = imageOriginal;
[picker pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[picker setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

My imagePickerControllerDidCancel method:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: put code of didfinishPicking..

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue in my crash logs. Can you reproduce it? Under what circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

It reproduces on ios 7.x .
Steps to reproduce:

1. Open image picker in the application.
2. Open "Camera Roll".
3. Press on home button (you should't terminate application).
4. Go to "Photos".
5. Remove last photos.
6. Open the application.

To solve it I subscribe to notification UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification and remove UIImagePickerViewController.

```
if ([self _isIOS7])
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_applicationDidEnterToBackgroundNotification:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
}
...

- (void)_applicationDidEnterToBackgroundNotification:(NSNotification*)notificaiton
{
    if ([self.owner presentedViewController] != nil)
    {
        [self _dismissImagePicker:NO];
    }
}
```